# How to test python code containing blank lines in the interpreter

Tags: python

It seems the python interpreter decides "it is now time to execute your code" when it sees a newline.  Is there any workaround to this?

The scala equivalent is to run ":paste" on a code snippet.

BTW we have environment restrictions so the intent is to use strictly the python interpreter (2.6.X) and not something "nicer" like ipython or a different python version.

Comment: Why not save your code to `mycode.py` and execute it with `python mycode.py`? No pasting required.

Comment: @Kevin  With a series of code snippets it is convenient to keep the REPL open.  Closing it, creating various small files to run snippets, then restarting is not so good. Also there is a startup cost to our repl that is ~10 seconds.

Comment: There is no way around this. At least not as a feature you seem to wish for. You could use execfile to execute a file you keep your snippets in, or embed the code you care about into a function itself as local function you then later call from the outer one. The added level of indentation should keep the interpreter in a "keep it coming" mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a workaround, you could open a `block`, for example a `try`-`except` block, or an `if` block:

```
>>> if True:
...  #my statements
...  #which I don't want to execute right now
...  pass # or do_stuff()
...
```

or wrap your snipplet in a function and call it then.

The obvious solution would be to use an interpreter shell which has paste support, for example `ipython` (has `%paste` and `%cpaste`), but unfortunately that's not an option for you; the default python shell has no similar mechanism AFAIK.

Another workaround would be to save the snipplet into a tempfile and call `execfile(filename)`, or maybe use `exec(<pastedcode>)` for small snipplets.

Actually, combining `exec`, abusing multiline strings as heredocs, and implicit `_` might be the best workaround, seems pretty convenient:

```
>>> """
... x = 5
... y = x**2
... print(x,y)
... """
'\nx = 5\ny = x**2\nprint(x,y)\n'
>>> exec(_)
5 25
>>> x, y # above code was executed in current scope, see?
(5, 25)
```

Comment: Hi, clever ideas. However both the heredoc and the "if True" still end up with "Unexpected indent"

Comment: if "heredocs" won't work, then there is likely something wrong with your python code to begin with - or your terminal. Works here like a charm. You can always go the tempfile route, though.

Comment: oh, of course - if you attempt the "heredocs" approach, you have to look out for triple quotes in your source. They'll break it when they are the same kind as your heredoc quotes, of course.

Comment: i do not have triple quotes inside the heredoc.

Comment: This was the only answer and it did "try" to find a solution, so I'm going to accept at this point.